# jQuery - Why the validation rule doesn't support predefined value?

Tags: jquery

I defined two jQuery validation functions as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function LessThanValidator(event)
{
  var lowID = event.data.lowID;
  var highID = event.data.highID;
  var formID  = event.data.formID;
  var lowValue = parseInt( $(lowID).val() );
  //var lowValue = parseInt( $(lowID).attr("value") ); // this doesn't fix

  if ( isNaN(lowValue) ) {
    lowValue = 0;
    }

  $(highID).rules('remove', 'min');
  $(highID).rules('add', { min: lowValue });
  $(formID).validate().element( highID );

  return false;  
}

function LargerThanValidator(event)
{
  var lowID = event.data.lowID;
  var highID = event.data.highID;
  var formID  = event.data.formID;
  var highValue = parseInt( $(highID).val() );  
  //var highValue = parseInt( $(highID).attr("value") );  // this doesn't fix

  if ( isNaN(highValue) ) {
    highValue = 0;
    }

  $(lowID).rules('remove', 'max');
  $(lowID).rules('add', { max: highValue });
  $(formID).validate().element( lowID );  

  return false;
}


$(document).ready( function() {

    // validate the #regFormBody form when it is submitted
    $("#regFormBody").validate({
    debug: true,
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.insertAfter( element.parent() );
    },
    rules: {
        confeelow: { required: true, digits: true, maxlength: 10, max: isNaN(parseInt($("#confeehigh"))) ? 0 : parseInt($("#confeehigh")) },
       confeehigh: { required: true, digits: true, maxlength: 10, min: isNaN(parseInt($("#confeelow")))  ? 0 : parseInt($("#confeelow")) }
    },

    messages: {      
    confeelow: { max: "Please enter a value less than or equal to To (US$)" },
   confeehigh: { min: "Please enter a value greater than or equal to From (US$)" }
    }
  }); 

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $("#confeelow").bind("change", {lowID: "#confeelow", highID: "#confeehigh", formID: "#regFormBody"}, LessThanValidator);
    $("#confeehigh").bind("change", {lowID: "#confeelow", highID: "#confeehigh", formID: "#regFormBody"}, LargerThanValidator);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.error 
{
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="mainContent">
  <form id="regFormBody" name="regFormBody" method="post" action="">
   <fieldset>
    <div id="conFeeLowFld" class="row ">
     <label for="confeelow" class="label">Desired Consulting Fee From (US$) <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
     <div class="collection">
      <input type="text" class="" maxlength="32" size="32" value="" id="confeelow" name="confeelow" />
    </div>
    <div id="conFeeHighFld" class="row ">
     <label for="confeehigh" class="label">To (US$) <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
     <div class="collection">
      <input type="text" class="" maxlength="32" size="32" value="" id="confeehigh" name="confeehigh" />
    </div>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="fieldsCollection" id="saveMyProfileFld">
      <input type="submit"  value="Save My Profile" id="savemyprofile" name="savemyprofile" class="saveprofile"/>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I use the above functions to make sure that the value of lowID is always less or equal to highID.

I use the following script to set up the validation.

```
  $("#confeelow").bind("change", { lowID: "#confeelow", highID: "#confeehigh", formID: "#profileFormBody" }, LessThanValidator);
  $("#confeehigh").bind("change", { lowID: "#confeelow", highID: "#confeehigh", formID: "#profileFormBody" }, LargerThanValidator);
```

These two functions work pretty well. However, if I predefine the values for #confeehigh and #confeelow, then these fields cannot pass the validation test. I really cannot figure out why. Because without pre-populated values, these validation functions work well.

Here the HTML script that causes the problems:

```
<input type="text" class="" maxlength="32" size="32" value="12" id="confeelow" name="confeelow" />
<input type="text" class="" maxlength="32" size="32" value="23" id="confeehigh" name="confeehigh" />
```

In other words, if I manually enter 12 for confeelow and 23 for confeehigh, then the validation works well.

Without predefined value, I don't have any problems:

```
<input type="text" class="" maxlength="32" size="32" value="" id="confeelow" name="confeelow" />
<input type="text" class="" maxlength="32" size="32" value="" id="confeehigh" name="confeehigh" />
```

Can anyone give me some hints why it doesn't work for predefined value?

Thank you

```
///////////////// Update-001 ////////////////////
```

Some people may have this question for me: Why you have to use a default value if the code works with new entered data. Here is reason

```
1> First the user will be allowed to enter data 
2> Second the user will submit the form and store in DB 
3> When next time the user logins again

I have to repopulate the text field by using some code similar as follows:

<input type='text' value='<?php echo $fee; ?>' />
```

And this default value causes me validation problems.
Thank you

Comment: What happens when you substitute `val()` with `attr("value")`?

Comment: No. It still complains about the values.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're never receiving a `change` event.

Your initial max and min values aren't being set because the `parseInt` function cannot take a jQuery object.
You need to change `parseInt($("#confeehigh"))` to `parseInt($("#confeehigh").val())`

Comment: Hello SLakes,

By changing to parseInt($("#confeehigh").val()), it doesn't solve the problem. My script starts with this one in fact. I got some comments from Combrink, so I made a change.

If you run this code under in a localhost, you will see that the chagneevent is triggered. However, the Line 31 return invalid of this file http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js.

Without using a default value, then that function returns valid.

Very Strange!!, I assume this may be due to a bug in the form validation plugin.

Thank you