# How to define a default value for "input type=text" without using attribute 'value'?

Tags: html

I need to give a default value for input `type=text` field as follows:

```
<input type="text" size="32" value="" name="fee" />
```

There is one way to give this default value as I know:

```
<input type="text" size="32" value="1000" name="fee" />
```

Here is the question: Is it possible that I can set the default value without using attribute `value`?

As I know, if I set the enter the value 1000 manually, and then view the source through web browser the value is still empty. So I think there may be a method that I can use.

Comment: What's wrong with `value`?

Comment: @SLaks it's a bad idea for a programming language to reserve a keyword as ubiquitous as value. My guess is value here has a conflicting name with some other code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Javascript.

For example, using jQuery:

```
$(':text').val('1000');
```

However, this won't be any different from using the `value` attribute.

Comment: That won't actually set the default value.  The DOM property, *defaultValue*, would be necessary for that.

Comment: Actually, this is different from using the `value` attribute. View Source will not have `value="1000"` in it. Viewing rendered source still will, but regular source will not.

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative way. However it still doesn't fix my original problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606118/jquery-why-the-validation-rule-doesnt-support-predefined-value

Comment: @q087: See my answer to your other question; you have a different problem.

Answer (score 44):

You should rather use the attribute placeholder to give the default value to the text input field.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" size="32" placeholder="1000" name="fee" />
```

Comment: as of this post, the placeholder pseudo-element is only partially supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

Comment: @JoeMaffei caniuse.com refers to CSS support. The placeholder attribute is _fully supported by all browsers_ it's just a hassle to change the default styling of it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants to set a default *value*. Placeholder doesn't set the value.

Comment: From a usability viewpoint, using the placeholder as a storage for a default value is controversial. I had a similar idea and brought it up in the UX community. This is what I got: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/121017/html5-placeholder-attribute-used-to-hold-default-even-after-value-change

Comment: default value and placeholder are totally different things...

Comment: This just show the text as background, it doesn't set the default value.

Answer (score 22):

> Here is the question: Is it possible that I can set the default value without using attribute 'value'?

Nope: `value` is the only way to set the default attribute.

Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Hello Pekka,

Please see the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606118/jquery-why-the-validation-rule-doesnt-support-predefined-value

Answer (score 18):

You can change the `name` attribute by `id`, and set the value property using client script after the element is created:

```
<input type="text" id="fee" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('fee').value = '1000';
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

this is working for me

```
<input defaultValue="1000" type="text" />
```

or

```
let x = document.getElementById("myText").defaultValue;
```

Comment: `defaultValue` is a React feature for managing uncontrolled inputs. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with ordinary HTML.

Comment: @spiffytech `defaultValue` has nothing to do with React, it's part of the HTML DOM API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#defaultvalue or https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp.

Comment: It's standard as a DOM property that can be set at runtime, but it doesn't appear to be standard as an HTML element attribute. Here's a demo showing the element attribute doesn't work: https://codepen.io/spiffytech/pen/rNQywob

Comment: This does not work in Chrome or in Firefox in 2024

Answer (score 3):

A non-jQuery way would be setting the value after the document is loaded:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) { 
        document.getElementById('foo').value = 'bar';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The value is there. The source is not updated as the values on the form change. The source is from when the page initially loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use `defaultValue`:

```
<input defaultValue="1000" type="text" />
```